# What's the use of `offset` in the version of `Atomic::cmpxchg` in Hotspot?

Tags: java, c++, jvm-hotspot, compare-and-swap

[Here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/runtime/atomic.cpp) is a version of implementation of function `Atomic::cmpxchg` used for CAS:

```cpp
jbyte Atomic::cmpxchg(jbyte exchange_value, volatile jbyte* dest, jbyte compare_value) {
  assert(sizeof(jbyte) == 1, "assumption.");
  uintptr_t dest_addr = (uintptr_t)dest;
  // look here
  uintptr_t offset = dest_addr % sizeof(jint);
  volatile jint* dest_int = (volatile jint*)(dest_addr - offset);
  jint cur = *dest_int;
  jbyte* cur_as_bytes = (jbyte*)(&cur);
  jint new_val = cur;
  jbyte* new_val_as_bytes = (jbyte*)(&new_val);
  // ... and here
  new_val_as_bytes[offset] = exchange_value;
  while (cur_as_bytes[offset] == compare_value) {
    jint res = cmpxchg(new_val, dest_int, cur);
    if (res == cur) break;
    cur = res;
    new_val = cur;
    new_val_as_bytes[offset] = exchange_value;
  }
  return cur_as_bytes[offset];
}
```

In the code above, I want to know what the use of `offset` actually is. I think we could simply and directly comapre `cur_as_bytes` and `compare_value`, without any `offset`. So why do we need it and how does it work? Is it for alignment? Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware that this implements cas for a `byte` using `cmpxchg` operating on `int`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is for alignment. The posted code implements a single-byte compare-exchange, using an already existing int-based compare-exchange.

This gives a few problems that the code needs to solve:

- The int-based compare-exchange is restricted to reading int-aligned values, which means that you have to work out which of the (4?) bytes of the int you actually want to change. After all, the other bytes in the int must be unaffected
- When you then actually do the compare-exchange, it is only a failure if the single byte you are trying to alter has been changed behind your back. If any of the other bytes in the int have changed, then that is only a failure for the int-cmpxchg, but not a failure for the byte-cmpxchg

The part before the `while`-loop handles the first part of that, by creating an int-aligned pointer that the int-value can be read from, and then setting up the "int we expect to see" and "int we want to change to" values.

The loop then handles the second part, where the algorithm attempts the int-cmpxchg, and then retries any failures as long as it is one of the other bytes that have been changed from expected.